# How to edit soft deleted data without restore it in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-routing

I have used `SoftDelete` to delete an event from `events` table. `SoftDelete` is working fine. I have shown that `SoftDelete` event `withTrashed()` in view and it showing. Now i want to edit that `SoftDelete` event data without restore it. Is it possible?

I am getting an error ***400 - we could not find the page*** when i have tried it.

```
$data['events'] = $qBuilder->EventComplete()->withTrashed()
                    ->orderBy('events.event_date', 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('events.id')
                    ->paginate(AppHelper::getConfigValue('ADMIN-PAGINATION-LIMIT'));
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible like this:

```
Model::withTrashed()->find(5)->update(['attribute' => 'value']);
```

so you are using eloquent apply withTrashed - find single model (here with id = 5) and then you update attributes you want.

You haven't showed more but, but in your case assuming you use [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) you might need to adjust it to allow to find also soft deleted models:

```
Route::bind('user', function ($value) {
    return App\User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($value);
});
```